# Different behavior between PolygonInteractor / LineBuilder in Python / MatplotLib / Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have been trying to solve my problem without success. As a bit of background to explain the situation. I am developing a GUI tool (with Tkinter) that displays, creates or modify polygons and 2Dlines.

To do this, I am using a LineBuilder class [Link to class used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855074/interactive-line-in-matplotlib/64153406#64153406) and also the PolygonInteractor class [Link to class](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html).

As you can see they are very similar, and I checked that callbacks (in debug mode) are created similarly.
My main code, in both situation, calls each class (i'll take the Line2D example that doesn't work) from a menu created in the root window, that calls a class that creates an sub-window (just to save the new line for example). (the code it not supposed to work "as-is" it's just for illustration of the algorithm):

```
class create_Road(tk.Toplevel):   # called from menu of main app
def __init__(self, master):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
    self.master.status_bar.config(text="Creating a new 2DLine...")

    ttk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=lambda: self.quitAR()).pack(side="bottom", padx=5, pady=5)
    ttk.Button(self, text="Save Area", command=lambda: self.saveAR())\
        .pack(side="bottom", padx=5, pady=5)

    fig, ax = Models.openmodel(modelname)   # this creates a matplolib used everywhere in the app
    self.fig = fig
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    dx = (xlim[1] - xlim[0]) / 4
    dy = (ylim[1] + ylim[0]) / 2
    line = Line2D([xlim[0] + dx, xlim[1] - dx], [dy, dy], linestyle=':', color='red',
                  marker='o', markerfacecolor='yellow')

    ax.add_line(line)   # add a line to the axes determined before
    linebuilder = LineBuilder(ax, line)  # call the class as mentionned in the link above

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', lambda event: self.AR_handle_close(event))
    fig.canvas.manager.window.wm_geometry(str(self.master.winfo_width() - 330) + "x" +
                                          str(self.master.winfo_height() - 50) + "+300+30")
    fig.show()
```

The LineBuilder _ _ init _ _ method is the folowing :

```
class LineBuilder(object):

epsilon = 30 #in pixels

def __init__(self, ax, line):
    canvas = line.figure.canvas
    self.line = line
    self.axes = ax
    self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
    self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())

    self.ind = None
    canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press_callback)
    canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_callback)
    self.canvas = canvas
```

My problem is that none of the events handling in the class LineBuilder works in this module. I creates a PolygonInteractor in the same module and it works perfectly. What I mean is I have some print('message') for each methods of the event handling, and none of them are called back for the LineBuilder class.

What surprises me is if I run the code in debug mode, and I set a breakpoint just before the code returns to the self.tk.mainloop(n), then I works perfectly. And if I use the PolygonInteractor in the same module, everything works fine.

Anyway, thank you in advance for any help! I could cheat and use the PolygonInteractor to manipulate these lines but... well...

Kristen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Hope it will help someone. I got a hint on another page mentioning week-reference to event handling. It was the key to answer this problem.
I only had to modify this to have the line builder working:

```
self.linebuilder = LineBuilder(ax, line)
```

Instead of only linebuilder = ...

Well, one challenge solved. Thank you anyway to the wonderful community of StackOverflow. Lots of help here...

Krys